# Picklist Values retrieved from custom object in visuaforce page becomes a default value after page refresh

Tags: apex, visualforce, picklist

Once clicking on save after selecting picklist, It gets saved as a record but becomes default value in VF Page after saving it. How can I retain the last selected value of picklist in visualforce page?

```
 <apex:inputfield value="{!wrapper.obj.picklistvalue}"  style="min-width: 2rem;" />
```

Comment: I posted a pretty generic answer but if you can provide a more in-depth code sample I might be able to help you more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

### Overview

The variable your controller is using is ending up with an outdated copy of the record. The Cliff notes are, you'll probably need to update your code to run a query for your record.

### Basic

If what you're doing is relatively simple, you shouldn't really have to do anything.

### Page

```
<apex:page controller="testPageController">
    <apex:form id="renderTarget">
        <apex:inputField value="{!c.Level__c}"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" reRender="renderTarget" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

### Controller

```
public class testPageController {
    public Contact c {get; set;}

    public testPageController() {
        Id cId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cId');
        this.c = [SELECT Id, Level__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :cId];
    }

    public void save() {
        upsert this.c;
    }
}
```

### Lazy Loading

As it gets more complicated, you may have to re-query for the record (for instance, if the view state were to be cleared).

In these circumstances, I have found that adding a query into the getter works fairly straightforward. There are some reasons why you don't want to do this either but I'm going to keep things simple:

```
public class testPageController {
    public Contact c {
        get {
            if (this.c == null) {
                Id cId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('cId');
                this.c = [SELECT Id, Level__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :cId];
            }

            return this.c;
        }

        set;
    }

    public testPageController() {}

    public void save() {
        upsert this.c;
    }
}
```

this means that if the page ever attempts to access the variable while it is null, it is re-grabbed from the DB.

Comment: Thanks @gNerb but the problem is like there are multiple vf page tabs in a single component. Selecting value from picklist and switching to another tab, then returning back to the old tab clears the picklist value

Comment: @Priyalakshmi As I said in my comment on your answer, if you provide a more thorough code sample we can help you resolve your issue. It sounds like what you're looking for is closer to what I have under my lazy loading section.

Answer (score -1):

When you always want to get the last selected value you have to save it somewhere and query this value each time you load the page.
You could youe custom settings for this. Or a custom field in a object.